# How to set dynamic og tag set in react app

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented dynamic meta title and meta description in my website. It is working fine for google crawling but when I try to check the preview of my any URL, it's just showing the main domain page meta title and meta description instead of actual page's meta data.

I want to set meta title, meta description and og tags data from my database dynamically.

Comment: I suggest you look into React Helmet

Comment: literally just searched "reactjs dymamic og tag"! Same day. Nice.